# Calculating the depth of a tree graph defined by a dictionary of edges

Tags: python, dictionary, math, tree, graph-theory

I have dictionary which maps individual nodes to a list of nodes that they are connected to. I need to generate a tree graph (not binary), and then calculate it's depth (longest way from top to bottom). What is the best way to do this?

**Example:**

```
graph = {
             1 : [],
             2 : [],
             3 : [2, 4],
             4 : [1, 5],
             5 : []
        }
```

[image]

Answer = 3 (you need to pass maximally 3 nodes to get to the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/):

### Code:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.dag import dag_longest_path

graph = {
             1 : [],
             2 : [],
             3 : [2, 4],
             4 : [1, 5],
             5 : []
        }

#Create directed graph
G = nx.DiGraph(graph)

#Find longest path in tree:
path = dag_longest_path(G)
```

### Output:

```
>>> path
[3, 4, 5]
>>> len(path)
3
```